# Post Special Characters to web API from angular application

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, .net-core, http-post

**API post method is as show below,**

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage CreateTemplate([FromUri]string templateName)
{
    //Code...
}
```

**and Angular post method is as show below,**

```
CreateTemplate(templateName: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(Url + "Templates/CreateTemplate?templateName=" + templateName, "");
}
```

How can I send the special characters to web API? If I try to send special characters, I will end up with receiving null in Web API.

Answer (score 3):

The # indicates a fragment, it and everything after it doesn't get sent to the server.

Given you use it as a query string parameter, you need to percent-encode it:

```
templateName=" + encudeURIcomponent(templateName)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent